# LFS Linux kernel won't boot - black screen

Tags: kernel, boot, grub2, lfs

I've recently completed an LFS build using GRUB-2.03~beta, and 
I've installed this using UEFI. When I boot linux however, I'm greeted 
with a black screen. I'm unsure how to debug this as the kernel doesn't 
even panic nor does it show a cursor, it just sits 100% black edge to edge.

Here are some configuration files

.config: http://sprunge.us/SMcc

/etc/fstab

```
# Begin /etc/fstab

# file system  mount-point  type     options             dump  fsck
#                                                              order

UUID=d6788259-f948-4164-ae29-d1b996ffd6d9     /            ext4    
defaults            1     1
UUID=04ED-C3D3     /boot/efi    vfat     defaults            0     1
efivarfs       /sys/firmware/efi/efivars  efivarfs  defaults  0      1

# End /etc/fstab

/boot/grub/grub.cfg

# Begin /boot/grub/grub.cfg
set default=0
set timeout=5

insmod ext2
set root=(hd0,gpt2)
insmod efi_gop
insmod efi_uga
insmod font
if loadfont /grub/unicode.pf2; then
   loadfont /grub/unicode.pf2
   set gfxmode=auto
   insmod gfxterm
   set gfxpayload=keep
   terminal_output gfxterm
fi

menuentry "GNU/Linux, Linux From Scratch"  {
   linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.7.2-lfs-7.10-systemd 
root=UUID=d6788259-f948-4164-ae29-d1b996ffd6d9 rw quiet
}
```

Mount tree in Arch linux host:

```
sdc      8:32   0 931.5G  0 disk
├─sdc2   8:34   0 931.3G  0 part /mnt/lfs
└─sdc1   8:33   0   260M  0 part /mnt/lfs/boot/efi
```

UUID's:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 29 14:42 04ED-C3D3 -> ../../sdc1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 29 14:42 
d6788259-f948-4164-ae29-d1b996ffd6d9 -> ../../sdc2
```

I've corrected the root from what it would be on Arch Host (`(hd2,gpt2)`
being mounted as `/dev/sdc`) to when I investigate on grub command line 
`(hd0,gpt2)`, so it is finding the kernel. I've attempted to switch out 
UUID's for `/dev/sdX`, however this still fails. Grub2 efi-directory was 
set to `/boot/efi` on installation. All the correct kernel options were 
set during compilation for UEFI installations.

I will attempt to re-compile the kernel with an arch based configuration file, and at least eliminate the possibility of a bad configuration.

Comment: Is anything being printed in /var/log/kern.log? The kernel may be starting to boot, but perhaps something is wrong with the display drivers. I'm having a similar issue getting my custom-built kernel to work. It seems like configuring it correctly for specific hardware is quite a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

The system may actually booted, it may be graphics mode that shows only black screen. I got similar issue when switched from 3.10 to 4.x kernel on RHEL.

I didn't find a solution how to load 4.x kernel in VESA mode.

You can disable GFX mode by setting terminal_output to "console" and remove gfx* settings in grub. This will let you see if system can boot.

Comment: Is there a serial line or Intel AMT on the host you could use for low-level access?

Comment: I already have access to console.The answer was targeted to original poster or other people that may have black screen after boot with 4.x kernel.